# Cannot compile SVG into Handlebars HTML template

Tags: javascript, svg, handlebars.js, html-email

I am compiling handlebars templates on the backend to send as an HTML email message. Some of my messages need to contain server-generated SVGs - QRCodes.

I made a simple Handlebars helper using an existing library - `qrcode-svg`. The code looks like:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('qrcode', (data) => {
  const svg = new QRCode({
    content: data,
    width: 90,
    height: 90,
    xmlDeclaration: false,
    join: true
  }).svg();
  return svg;
});
```

The library that I am using is working fine standalone. My template has a fragment like:

```
            {{#each tickets}}
            <div style="...">
              <div style="...">
                {{{qrcode payload}}}
              </div>
              <div>{{title}}</div>
              <div>{{sequence}}</div>
            </div>
            {{/each}}
```

If I use the no-escape `{{{...}}}` version or set `noEspace` to true in Handlebars options, I get a bunch of `<u></u>` inside my HTML email.

If I use `{{qrcode payload}}` normally, I do the an svg, only it is `"<svg.../>"` e.g. my svg is surrounded by double quotes and the email does not render correctly. I see not the SVG, but the HTML code representing it.

What should I do?

Comment: `the email does not render correctly` Where are you looking at the rendered HTML?

Comment: gmail. it forces to make styles embedded, but SVGs should still work, right?

Comment: https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-svg/. Traditionally, email support for SVG has never been great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<u></u>` code you mention makes me think you checked this on Gmail’s desktop webmail, which does not support neither [embedded SVG](https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-svg/) nor [external SVG](https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-svg/).

If your image is an essential part of your content and you want most people to see it, make sure to use a better supported format like JPG, GIF or PNG.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something else. Forked the node-svg library and taught it to print HTML tables. If useful, feel free to use/clone/fork it from  https://github.com/Diophant/qrcode-svg-table